# How to calculate the memory needed for processing an image?

Tags: php, memory, image-processing

I want to put some restrictions to the images uploaded by the users, so the script that process them never runs out of memory.

The images that take more memory, are the ones with higher resolution. They don't need to have a big size in bytes. For example, a 46kb image, with 4000x2500 resolution, and some transparencies (PNG), took around 90mb to resize it.

Is there a way to precalculate the memory needed accurately?

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about image manipulation, but wouldn't the Uncompressed Bitmap filesize be in the general ballpark?

Comment: General rule of thumb that I use: horizontal * vertical * 4 just to load the image using GD, plus the same calculation for the resized image... in bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the rule of thumb is, width x height x 4 (rgba) for both the source and destination images, and don't forget about the amount of memory the script itself has already consumed.

Comment: It's not working. I have this: (4000*2462 + 300*185) * 4 / 1024 / 1024 = 37.78mb. The script, without the image processing part, takes around 1mb. With the image processing, takes 86.77mb.

Comment: That is peculiar, it has always worked for me. For testing, you can always try printing `memory_get_usage(true)` before and after the image calls to give you an idea of exactly how much is being used, and devise your own algorithm.

Comment: Maybe the image library I'm using is doing something stupid. But I tested it with another library, and the same happened. I'm sure it works fine if I only use GD, so I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You weren't using GD? lol I often forget there is more than just GD out there. Thanks for the accept, I hope it works for you, and it was with GD in mind, I have never personally used ImageMagick or others.

Comment: I'm using one library that wraps the GD library, and another library that wraps the Imagick library (php wrapper for ImageMagick). Both gave me the same results, so I'll stick to the one that uses GD.

Answer (score 0):

Using the GD library once the file has been uploaded you can use [getimagesize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php). You can then check the height and width to determine if you want to process it or return an error, it also returns the number of bits used per color if you want to take that into account as well.

So your validation can be on file size and dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one :)

Using exiftool to get the metadata of the image:

```
exiftool image.png
```

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Size                       : 1347 kB
MIME Type                       : image/png
Image Width                     : 10000
Image Height                    : 10000
Bit Depth                       : 8
Color Type                      : RGB with Alpha
Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
Image Size                      : 10000x10000
Megapixels                      : 100.0
```

**Watching the Free RAM**:

Before Open the image

```
cat /proc/meminfo |grep MemFree
```

1396980 kB

after the img is opened

```
cat /proc/meminfo |grep MemFree
```

622660 kB

RAM consumption:

> (1396980-622660)/1024

= 756 MB

> 10000 * 10000 * 8/(1024*1024)

=762 MB

**aproximate RAM consumption in kB= (Image Width x Image Height x Bit Depth)/1024**