# PHP File uploading stops

Tags: php, image, memory, upload

For a client I have build a simple script that uploads multiple files(images), resizes them, stores them on a temporary folder and then later on move them to their destination.

Resizing is done using PHP's GD, as Imagick is not available.

These images are about 2/4 MB a piece and the client uploads about 30 images in one shot. 
I used HTML5's multiple="" attribute which all works fine.

In tests all worked fine because I used Windows standard wallpaper images.

I can't find the source of the problem.
When uploading more then 1 image, the script failes debugging tells me it does upload the second image but won't resize.

I checked the memory usage for the images which is aprox **105724352 bytes** each.

My PHP ini settings:

```
max_execution_time = 300     
max_input_time = 600    
memory_limit = 200M
```

So you see at the second image the memory reached it limit, making my script stop. Is that correct?

If so, how wise is it to upgrade the memory limit?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

It now seems the GD Function `imagecreatefromjpeg` cant handle files with a resolution bigger then 3500px wide, my files are bigger then 5000px wide.

Does anyone have a work arround for this?
At this point I am wondering if it is wise to have the client on a shared host at all if he needs so much memory for these images.

Comment: Try setting `ini_set('memory_limit','-1');` for test case. And say if the error persits.

Comment: Seems to work, all files are being processed. Thanks! But I think I should not batch the files

Comment: Even if you process only one image with a file size like 4MB, you probably need a higher memory_limit or unlimited (-1).

Comment: Do you have an example? Or best practice? Never worked with images this big and I sort of don't know for sure how to tackle it.

Comment: You can check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253732/how-to-calculate-the-memory-needed-for-processing-an-image . My company work with an image class where we do it like in my first comment. `ini_set('memory_limit','-1'); /*do stuff with big images*/ ini_restore('memory_limit');`.

Comment: I have tried it, it seems now after testing again something is wrong with the images. Or atleast, the image resizing script won't resize at all.

Comment: For setting a max size (150x200), you can do this for example
`ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
$ratio = min(150/$img_width, 200/$img_height, 1);
$w = round($ratio * $img_width); 
$h = round($ratio * $img_height);
ImageCopyResized($new_image, $org_image,0,0,0,0, $w, $h, $img_width, $img_height);
/*$new_image is the resized image resource*/
ini_restore('memory_limit');` I don't wanna make an answer out of that cause its not an answer of the original question.

Comment: The thing is, at `@imagecreatefromjpeg($file));` the script does nothing. If i `echo '1'` or something before `@imagecreatefromjpeg($file))` and `echo 'b'` after it I only get to see '1' so the `@imagecreatefromjpeg($file))` does not even open the file anymore. var dumping it does not provide any result either. What's going wrong?

Comment: The memory_limit change must placed before you load the image `ini_set('memory_limit','-1');` - You already have this? I think its better when you edit your question or create a new one.

Comment: Sorry.. got carried away with this. Yes I have it on top of the document, I ussually place configurations at the top or config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So you see at the second image the memory reached it limit, making my
>   script stop. Is that correct?

Check your Apache error logs under (**nix system) `/var/log/apache2/error.log` to see if it is really the problem.

> If so, how wise is it to upgrade the memory limit?

You should not hande multiple image operations in one script. Make ajax queries for each, handle them in seperate instances.

Comment: Thanks for your response, checked the error log and there are no errors

Comment: @VincentCohen Please make sure you enabled the error reporting and also check the access log as well. According to my experince, it should always drop some log records if there is a memory problem. If you don't see any records then your problem might not be a memory problem at all.

Comment: Pulling my hair out over here. Yes error logging is on as means of testing. No messages in any logs. I understand I should process each file seperratly instead of in a batch but i'd like to understand this aswell.